# frame size changes between viewdidload and viewwillappear in iOS7 and not iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller that loads from a xib. I am doing NOTHING with the size in code - it was all set up in the XIB file. I have logging set showing that iniwithnibname has correct width and height, viewdidload has correct width/height, viewwillappear has wrong width/height.

The width/height are changing to values that do not exist in my code.

This is an iPad landscape only app, and running it in simulator on 7.1 shows it broken, and 8.2 shows it OK.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

here is how I am loading the VC with the xib:

```
    ShareViewController *shareViewController = [[ShareViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShareViewController" bundle:nil imageName:imageSelected ];


    shareViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    float fW = shareViewController.view.frame.size.width;
    float fH = shareViewController.view.frame.size.height;
    shareViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(fW, fH);
    [self presentViewController:shareViewController animated:YES completion:^(){}];
```

In iOS8 simulator here is NSLog output:

```
KIStd[28103:762368] Entering ShareButtonPressed
KIStd[28103:762368] initWithNibName/image entry
KIStd[28103:762368] viewDidLoad entry
KIStd[28103:762368] viewDidLoad exit w:596.000000, h:400.000000
KIStd[28103:762368] initWithNibName/image exit w:596.000000, h:400.000000
KIStd[28103:762368] viewWillAppear Entry w:596.000000, h:400.000000
KIStd[28103:762368] viewWillAppear exit w:596.000000, h:400.000000
KIStd[28103:762368] viewDidAppear entry
KIStd[28103:762368] viewDidAppear exit w:596.000000, h:400.000000
```

In iOS7 simulator here is NSLog output:

```
KIStd[28186:60b] Entering ShareButtonPressed
KIStd[28186:60b] initWithNibName/image entry
KIStd[28186:60b] viewDidLoad entry
KIStd[28186:60b] viewDidLoad exit w:596.000000, h:400.000000
KIStd[28186:60b] initWithNibName/image exit w:596.000000, h:400.000000
KIStd[28186:60b] viewWillAppear Entry w:540.000000, h:620.000000
KIStd[28186:60b] viewWillAppear exit w:540.000000, h:620.000000
KIStd[28186:60b] viewDidAppear entry
KIStd[28186:60b] viewDidAppear exit w:540.000000, h:620.000000
```

This shows the problem quite clearly.

Comment: Did you use Layout constraints in your XIB ? If you didn't, layout behavior might be undefined...

Answer (score 8):

Never rely on frame and bound values in `viewDidLoad`/`viewWillAppear`. Usually the most precise location to listen to size changes is `viewDidLayout`, where you can keep track of the last seen size, and do your logic if the size changed.

`viewDidAppear` is precise, but is called after the view has already animated in, so you will see an ugly jump. `viewWillLayout`/`viewDidLayout` is usually the most precise one, as I mentioned before.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I don't want to change anything! I have a xib with 596W/400H. I have my labels/text/buttons all set up in the XIB. When the VC loads in 7.1 it is 540W/620H. I cannot see the right side of my VC which has buttons in it!  This works perfectly in iOS8, but NO in iOS7.1.

Comment: This was not clear to me from the question. Please post how you load your xib content.

Comment: updated with code requested and also with NSLog output

Comment: @Jerry, are `fW` and `fH` correct values in both cases?

Comment: NO - that is the issue - - looking at the log, you can see in iOS7 it changes to 540/620 wheres in iOS8 it stays put at 596/400 (which is my XIB size).

Comment: I think i may have answered the question wrong. fw and fh are what I am printing out in the Log - i neglected to mention that... Going into the presentViewController, bot 7 and 8 have the correct fw and fh.

Comment: As I said, until the system layouts the views you should not use the size. Instead, use constants in your code.

Comment: ok so what you are saying is that creating a XIB and laying everything out meticulously in there is NOT a good practice? That I would have to keep track of the w/h externally? That really doesn't make any sense. Where is the system getting the w/h from? I didn't set it anywhere... Why does it work perfect in iOS8? Something is missing here I fear...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a problem with size classes? Try to configure (See [About Designing for Multiple Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html)) or disable it.

[image: File Inspector - Size Classes]

Comment: I tried turning on 'Use Auto Layout' with no change in behavior. I am not designing for multiple screens - i am simply changing iOS version. It is the same iPad retina target.